# Prepared statement for MySQLi in php not working

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to pull a field from a table in MySQLi witih a prepared statement in php, but I keep getting an empty result.  I know the field is in the table, but nothing gets pulled.  Here's my code:

```
if (!($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT password from members WHERE username = \"Bill\""))) 
{
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
}


if (!$stmt->bind_result($result)){
    echo "Bind failed";
}

 $sql_searched_password = $result;
  echo $sql_searched_password."
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: After `bind_result` - `fetch` should be called. Refer to any mysqli tutorial or official documentation.

Comment: I got no error.  The echo command simply prints nothing.

Comment: I get "Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on null" when I try to fetch using $sql_searched_password = $result->fetch_assoc()

Comment: Btw, that isn't a "prepared" statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting to call `->fetch()` which is the command that pulls data from the result set into your bound variable.

You can also make your query easier to read and therefore debug, specially when the queries get more complex by using single quotes inside a double quoted string literal

```
if (!($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT password from members WHERE username = 'Bill'"))) 
{
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
}


if (!$stmt->bind_result($result)){
    echo "Bind failed";
}

$stmt->fetch();

echo $result;
```

In fact the point of preparing a query is so that you can pass parameters to it after preparation, and possibly so you can call the prepared statement multiple times, with different parameters.

So this might be a better example

```
if (!($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT password from members WHERE username = ?"))) 
{
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
}

if (!$stmt->bind_param("s", 'Bill')) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
}

if (!$stmt->bind_result($result)){
    echo "Bind failed";
}

$stmt->fetch();
echo $result;

// bind a new value to the existing prepared query
if (!$stmt->bind_param("s", 'William')) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
}

if (!$stmt->bind_result($result)){
    echo "Bind failed";
}

$stmt->fetch();

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling `$stmt->bind_result($result)` means that

> result will be binded to `$result` variable.

See - `will be binded`? `bind_result` not fetches your rows from db. Fetching rows done with `fetch`:

```
$stmt->bind_result($result);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $sql_searched_password = $result;
}

echo $sql_searched_password;

/* close statement */
$stmt->close();
```

Refer to [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.bind-result-examples).